# How do I disable domain masking on external links?

Tags: web-hosting, forwarding

I'm forwarding traffic from a url to a different hosting location using the "forward with masking" option on GoDaddy.  It is my understanding that this is a form of domain masking, in that the user types url http://www.[A].com in their browser, but they actually see the webpage hosted at http://www.[B].com

However, when clicking on an external link on the website, the external site appears, but the address bar still shows http://www.[A].com.  Is there a way to escape the domain masking for external links off the site?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is masking..
Your forwarding the user like a proxy with no changes to the "domain"
The domain is not changed, it just delivers content from another domain..

Is this not what you are looking for????

Comment: Yes, it is masking.  But the answer I am looking for, is whether there is "a way to escape the domain masking for external links off the site?"

Comment: Can you be a little more specific.. with an example or two.. please :D